# Lens distortion

Tags: image-processing, camera, computer-vision, camera-calibration

Suppose I have a 240x180 camera with the following distortion coefficients,

```
k1 = -0.138592767408, k2=0.0933736664192, k3=0.0, p1=-0.000335586987532, p2=0.000173720158228
```

The camera center is given to be `u0, v0 = 129.924663379, 99.1864303447`.

[image: distortion_formula_1]
[image: distortion_formula_2]

In the above formulae, p1=k4 and p2=k5, u and v are the undistorted co-ordinates and ud, vd the corresponding distorted ones.

My understanding of the undistorted co-ordinates is that it is a mapping of every undistorted co-ordinate to a distorted one. Therefore, the ranges of both undistorted and distorted co-ordinates should be between (0-240, 0-180). However, going by the above formula, I get extremely high numbers for distorted co-ordinates if I input undistorted co-ordinates in the range(0-240, 0-180) which goes against this understanding. Have I done something wrong here?

Comment: How much is your `r` ?

Comment: `r`  keeps varying depending on the camera co-ordinate. It is calculated according to the formula given above.

Comment: about 164 for `u=0`, `v=0`

Comment: Then there is some scaling problem. For example, the term `k2^4` is huge. Shouldn't `r` be somehow normalized ?

Comment: Do you use SI units like meter or mm? Moreover, origin of the coordinate system is in the middle of camera frame.

Comment: @SlawomirOrlowski: no, it is top left.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I am using this resource for the formualae http://rpg.ifi.uzh.ch/docs/teaching/2018/02_image_formation_1.pdf . Although they mention about normalisation in the pdf, it doesn't seem to me that the `u` and `v` used in the formulae are normalised.

Comment: Yeah they mention `u_bar`, `v_bar` in that slide, but further below they use `u` and `v` in all their formulae. I assumed they must be following a convention

Comment: @YvesDaoust guess you were right about the normalisation. I checked another source. http://ais.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/teaching/ws10/robotics2/pdfs/rob2-10-camera-calibration.pdf . I guess the guys at Zurich must have made a mistake while preparing the slides. Thanks.